# C# Razor - Display comment where looped in value equals selectedIndex value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a select list that looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control">
     <option>Select</option>
     <option value="2">Order</option>
     <option value="5">Delivery</option>
     <option value="6">PickUp</option>
     <option value="13">Quote</option>
</select>
```

Once a user selects an option, I would like to display a comment only where `db_Type` = the value of the selected option:

```
foreach (var note in Model.GetNotes)
    {
        <div class="current-note-container">
            <h5 class="note-comment"><b>Description:</b><br/> @note.db_Comment.Where(note.db_Type == /* Selected Index */)</h5>
        </div>
    }
```

I'm not really sure how I can accomplish this using razor, or how to mix javascript in to get the job done.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should've added the tag - MVC 4

Comment: Why not do it via JQuery? C# is server side scripting while JQuery is client side scripting designed for these things

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do it with jQuery, but I was having trouble figuring out the syntax since `@note.db_Type` is coming from my Model

Comment: does the integer value has a purpose? Else you can save the comment in the dropdown value

Comment: The integer value is the value I am trying to compare to `db_Type` in order to only display one note type at a time.

Comment: One way of doing this is calling an action asynchronously (through ajax) that retrieves the comment based on the selected id. But I think there must some easier way..

Comment: You can bind to `change` event of select and show the display comment after toggling the visibility. However, that requires @note,db_comment value available at client-side; so if the data is not sensitive and huge in size then you can keep the comments as hidden in html (at client-side). If it sensitive or huge then recommendation is to use `ajax` request to get the comment based on selected option from server.

Answer (score 0):

Razor is a server side code and so you can not combine it with client script like what you are planning to.

Instead use jQuery to listen to the [selection changed event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and pass ([GET](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)/[POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)) newly selected value back to controller and query database and get the required comment.

**jQuery inside View** (pseudo code):

```
$( "#ddlOptions" ).change(function() { //assuming ddlOptions is the Id of select list
    var selectedOptionId= $(this).val();             
    $.get('@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")', { id: selectedOptionId}, 
      //You can use $.get(...) or $.post(...) based on action method type.
       function (data) {
          //Display/append the comment received to a container(div/span etc)
    });
});
```

**Controller code** (pseudo code)

```
public JsonResult Get(int id)
{
     //Query database here based on id to get the comment
     //e.g: db_comment.where(com=>com.id==id).FirstOrDefault();

     return Json(comment,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope this provide you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact, but I'm think you're looking for something like this

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="GetComment(this.value)">
     <option>Select</option>
     <option value="2">Order</option>
     <option value="5">Delivery</option>
     <option value="6">PickUp</option>
     <option value="13">Quote</option>
</select>
```

Add this to the script of your razor view

```
function GetComment(ID)
{
    var parameters = {};

    parameters["ListID"] = ID;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        data: parameters,
        url: "/MyController/GetComment",
        success: function (message) {
            $('#note-comment').val(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

And finally something like this to your controller

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetComment(int ListID)
{
    return Json(Mylist[ListID].Comment);
}
```